# I can't able to see the .htaccess file

Tags: php

am using Digitalocean VPS

I can't see the `.htaccess` file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls
000-default.conf default-ssl.conf dindudu.conf script.conf site.conf
```

how to make the `.htaccess` file .

Comment: try  `sudo find / -name .htaccess`

Comment: what is your project folder?

Comment: sudo find / -name .htaccess 
/root/.composer/cache/.htaccess
/root/.composer/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -a`.

`ls` without parameters does not list file names beginning with a dot.
And have a look at `man ls`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new file named .htaccess in your public directory eg. /var/www/html and start using it .. 
Please note you might have to mention Allowoveride All in you apache config or your virtual host file .. 
Please refer this link for this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file